# How to call a function for all inputs as default

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a function as **default** for some inputs.

for example I have a removeComma function

```
function removeComma(e)...


<input onChange={myChange} value={myValye}  /* using attr,ref or anything to detect this input and calling removeComma*/ />
```

I have multi inputs inside multi components.

Comment: "detect this input and calling `removeComma` ". Do you mean calling the function in real time when the user inputs?

Comment: @RifkyNiyas yes. removeComma calling first then calling onChange. I don't want to calling this for each input.

Comment: You could create a re-usable `Input` component and inside that component, add an `onChange` event handler that first calls `removeComma` and then calls the change event handler passed as a prop by to this `Input` component.

Comment: I think  @Yousaf 's solution would be the way to go. Can we see the content of  `removeComma` and the `myChange` functions?